# Giving ShadowText a location on the bing map in WPF

Tags: wpf, bing-maps, bing-api

So i have created a ShadowText object that has some text inside and that is rendering on screen on top of my map rite now. What I'm trying to figure out how to do is make it so that i can give my ShadowText object a "Location" on the map so this way it acts just like the country text on the map. Aka the text maintains its latitude and longitude when the user scrolls and or zooms the map. Rite now i can only seem to get it rendering in screen space and not with a "Location". Or if someone knows of a type that can draw text with bing maps in WPF that would be easier to manipulate than ShadowText by all means im all ears. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You should just re-purpose the Pushpin. Create a custom data template for the Pushpin and have your ShadowText be inside the control template.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CutomPushpinTemplate" TargetType="map:Pushpin">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid Margin="0">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                  Margin="0" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<maps:Pushpin Location="{Binding YourLocation}"
              PositionOrigin="Center"
              Template="{StaticResource CustomPushpinTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourContent}" />
</maps:Pushpin>
```

Comment: I gave that a shot already but it didn't work out very well. Basically I'm trying to render information over all the countries on the map so when i tried to use the pushpins to render my information everything just became WAY to cluttered on screen. So i'm trying to just find a way where i can use only text =/

Comment: The idea is to not keep the actually pushpin visuals, but use a template to only show the user your text. I added example code to my answer. This way it looks like you are just displaying text over the map and not using Pushpins at all.

Comment: Bryan thank you for the help! Could you possibly supply some example c# code...we have a standard and most of our logic has to exist outside of the xaml. Thank you again! i look forward to implementing this solution.

Comment: That seems like a rather odd and unfortunate standard. Converting the above xaml into C# should be straight forward, however, converting it myself goes a bit beyond the effort I'm willing to put into answering questions on SO. Sorry.